# Is importing a file good in Python

Tags: python

I have around 80 lines of a function in a file. I need the same functionality in another file so I am currently importing the other file for the function.

My question is that in terms of running time on a machine which technique would be better :- importing the complete file and running the function or copying the function as it is and run it from same package.

I know it won't matter in a large sense but I want to learn it in the sense that if we are making a large project is it better to import a complete file in Python or just add the function in the current namespace.....

Comment: You're really asking if you should import modules in python? http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Come on, you *can't* be serious... please?

Comment: Copy-and-paste is almost the single most expensive programming mistake you can make.  Doubling the volume of code more than doubles the cost to maintain.  Why would you consider copy-and-paste?   What made it seem like a good idea?  Please elaborate on the appeal behind copy-and-paste.

Comment: @S.Lott, ...unless you are paid per line of code :)

Comment: Srry all, I was't aware that we can import just a single function too from a module so I was thinking why too always load the entire namespace ..... Thanks a lot anyways...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Importing is how you're supposed to do it. That's why it's possible. Performance is a complicated question, but in general it really doesn't matter. People who really, really need performance, and can't be satisfied by just fixing the basic algorithm, are not using Python in the first place. :) (At least not for the tiny part of the project where the performance really matters. ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Importing is good cause it helps you manage stuff easily. What if you needed the same function again? Instead of making changes at multiple places, there is just one centralized location - your module.

In case the function is small and you won't need it anywhere else, put it in the file itself.

If it is complex and would require to be used again, separate it and put it inside a module.

Performance should not be your concern here. It should hardly matter. And even if it does, ask yourself - does it matter to you?

Comment: "What if you needed the same function again?" Exactly, but even more importantly: what if you're already using it in several places, but now you've found a bug? If you'd organized things properly, you'd only have to fix it once.

Answer (score 0):

[Copy/Paste](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_and_paste_programming) cannot be better. Importing affects load-time performance, not run-time (if you import it at the top-level).

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of importing is to allow code reuse and organization.

Remember too that you can do either

```
import MyModule
```

to get the whole file or

```
from MyModule import MyFunction
```

for when you only need to reference that one part of the module.

Answer (score 0):

If the two modules are unrelated except for that common function, you may wish to consider extracting that function (and maybe other things that are related to that function) into a third module.